# Download Connection From LinkedIn and import into iPhone Contacts

Tags: ios, linkedin-api

Can anyone help me , I want to Download the connection of LinkedIn and Add into iPhone Address Book.

I googled it but not getting any help.

I am using following Api :

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/connections"];
```

and I am getting the response like:

```
   profile {
    errorCode = 0;
    message = "Access to connections denied";
    requestId = GVG2FXA2N0;
    status = 403;
    timestamp = 1366641414499;
   }
```

Comment: The problem is getting the data from linkedin or import it to the Address Book?

Comment: but it is already done in Linked Official App. Goto setting ->Download Connection

Comment: Don't understand - I'm asking again -> What is the problem exactly? Adding the info to the local address book?

Comment: i am not able to get the connections from LinkedIn.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: message = "Access to connections denied";
I guess you don't have the right to access to API. I don't know how linkedIn API works but I supposed you need a token or a key to use it, do you have one ?

Comment: Yes I have Appkey and secrecykey, using for login through  LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

There is AddressBook framework for that:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/

a wrapper library:

http://maniacdev.com/2012/02/open-source-ios-address-book-wrapper-library-providing-automatic-hashing-and-permission-alerts/

Simple tutorial:

http://programming4.us/mobile/9260.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You must be missing r_network scope.Even I was getting same error. But when I added r_network scope the problem resolved